# How to get and make request with Cookies

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I tried to make request using fetch API, but when I do `console.log(response.headers.get("Set-Cookie"))` I got `undefined`.
Is there any way to do requests with `cookie` persisting across requests?

Comment: Oh, I read source code and seems what android implentation currently doesn't have cookies :(

Comment: I've used https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies, may be a good option for you.

Comment: It doesn't help in my issue, and it work only on iOS :(

Comment: How about AsyncStorate? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: How async storage help me get cookies from http-request?

Answer (score 1):

`Set-Cookie` can't be read programmatically. Check this out => [github/fetch#receiving-cookies](https://github.com/github/fetch#receiving-cookies)

> Like with XMLHttpRequest, the Set-Cookie response header returned from the server is a forbidden header name and therefore can't be programatically read with response.headers.get(). Instead, it's the browser's responsibility to handle new cookies being set (if applicable to the current URL). Unless they are HTTP-only, new cookies will be available through document.cookie.